# Is it possible to make comments private on certain disqus threads?

Tags: javascript, disqus

I have some urls where I want the comments only viewable to the people with access to that page.

As it is now, these comments and users are being referenced in the Community tab as "Top Commenters" and "Top Discussions".  I want to omit any of these comments from being displayed here.

I thought this might be manageable in the configuration variables but I don't see it yet.

https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472098-javascript-configuration-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no concept of "private" threads on Disqus at the time of this answer. However, there's a few techniques to obscure threads so they aren't as easily discovered/posted on. This is appropriate for invite/read-only discussions.

1. Register a new Disqus shortname: https://disqus.com/admin/register --
   This keeps the threads and top users from being aggregated on your "public" section
2. Use this new shortname on the "private" pages of your website.
3. Optionally, you can turn on pre-moderation for all comments, and simply whitelist the users you don't want to be pre-moderated.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately almost every thread is designed to be its own private community that shouldn't know about the others.  I'll see what I can come up with in terms of a new short name.

Comment: Additionally - there is no way to hide the Community tab, correct?

Comment: This seems to indicate that no - you cannot remove it, unless something has changed since June 2014 https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/disqus-dev/yn6aWXJXMQE

Comment: That answer is still right, the community tab can't be hidden. Just to be perfectly honest, Disqus might not be the best solution here. It's as much a network as it is a comment system, so it might not be worth fighting against.

Comment: Thanks for all the information.  We may have to go homegrown as you suggest, but we really like disqus and just got the SSO going :).